# threads having the same name

Tags: java, multithreading

I have read one thing about `threads` in the Java thread model API. It says that more than one thread can have the same name. But the PID of each thread will be unique, right? What is the name then? Is not the thread class name?

Comment: yeah, but i thought, the name will also be used somewhere by JVM. so, the name is just a specification for human to identify the thread among other threads..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> what is the name then? isnot the thread class name?

The name is whatever you set it to be using [`Thread.setName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29). It's just for the purpose of diagnostics. If you don't call `Thread.setName` or provide the name to the constructor, the value will be determined as per the docs:

> Allocates a new Thread object. This constructor has the same effect as `Thread (null, null, gname)`, where gname is a newly generated name. Automatically generated names are of the form `"Thread-"+n`, where n is an integer.

(It's obviously more useful diagnostically to give a specific thread name which indicates its purpose.)

Comment: hey Jon. thanks, now i remembered the method ``setName()`` but what name will be given if i dont set the name?

Answer (score 6):

When a new thread is created, it is assigned an automatically generated name which is of the form - `"Thread-0"`, `"Thread-1"`.

But, you can any time change the name of the Thread by using [`Thread#setName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29) method: -

```
Thread.currentThread().setName("ABC");
```

`Thread.currentThread()` returns the reference to current thread executing, and then you set the name of that thread to `"ABC"`.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry for dumb question :)

Comment: @doniyor. It's perfectly ok. No question is dumb. You can ask any question, but you should first try to sort it out on your own.

Comment: yeah, i was just reading java api out of interest and came across to this doc. i just immediately thought of pid, but not of the name.. anyway, many thanks for your time and explanation! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope it is a thread name, If you see a thread dump, you will know which thread is doing what exactly. :)